# MYSQL GUID Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error, guid

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE GUID(guid BINARY(16),user VARCHAR(16),expire INT(10));
```

My goal is to create a default guid if a row has a guid = null.
To do this, I am creating a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER default_guid 
BEFORE INSERT ON GUID
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF new.guid IS NULL THEN
SET new.guid = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', ''));
END IF;
END;
```

However, I receive the following syntax error when creating this trigger:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 5

I have tried several online syntax checkers with no luck; where is my syntax error?

Comment: Are you setting the delimiter before running this statement?

Comment: No, I did not think it was necessary; I receive the same error even when i input the code as a one-liner

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL uses a semicolon (`;`) to terminate statements. However, when creating a trigger, you have several statements which make it up, so you need to tell MySQL that the semicolons aren't marking that you're done with the trigger definition, just with that statement. This can be done by setting the delimiter to another character combination, e.g., `$$`:

```
-- Set the delimiter to $$
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER default_guid 
BEFORE INSERT ON GUID
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.guid IS NULL THEN
        SET new.guid = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(), '-', ''));
    END IF;
END;
$$ -- Trigger ends here

-- Reset the delimiter to ;
DELIMITER ;
```